# ASP.Net: Dynamic JavaScript path / src

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I try to make Folder for things in my ASP.Net Application (e.g. all with Finance in /Finance).

No I bind an JavaScript in the MainPage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Helper/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

But when I now open ~/Finance/Payment.aspx I get an JavaScript Error with "Path ~/Finance/Helper/jquery..." not found.

What to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your path `Helper/jquery-1.3.2.min.js` is a relative path. So when you go into `/Finance` the browser is looking for jQuery in `/Finance/Helper/jquery-1.3.2.min.js`.

A simple way around this is to use absolute paths

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Helper/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can use a [ScriptManager](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/ScriptManagerOverview.aspx) which allows you to use the tilde

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Helper/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

As a last resort if you have issues with the ScriptManager you can also do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Helper/jquery-1.3.2.min.js") %>">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx) in the script src attribute (you'll need to make the path to your JavaScript file an app root relative path with the "~/"):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Helper/jquery-1.3.2.min.js") %>"></script>
```